# How can we prove this for n=5, 13 and any values?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, problem-solving, word-problem

A man has to paint n consecutive mile posts and wants to do this as inefficiently as possible - So that he walks as far as possible from the first post he paints to the last post he paints. He can only turn around and go back the other way immediately after painting a post, and each post can only be painted once. How should he do this if =5, and if =13?

Can you generalise this to any ?

I know we have to work from the middle post and then go to first last second second last and so on. But how would i write a proof for this?

Answer (score 0):

Let the posts be painted in the sequence $a_1, a_2, \ldots a_n$.

The distance that he walks is

$$|a_1 - a_2 | + | a_2 - a_3| + \ldots | a_n - a_{n-1}|. $$

This can be expressed as
$$\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i - a_{i+1} | = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \pm a_i + \sum_{i=2}^n \pm a_i.$$

with the following conditions:

1. There are $n-1$ + signs and $n-1$ - signs.
2. $a_i$ is negative iff $a_{i+1}$ is positive and $ ai < a_{i+1}$

For now, ignoring the second condition, we see that the maximum value is achieved at:

$$ -2 \times 1 -2 \times 2 -2 \times 3 +\ldots \text{check the middle}  + \ldots + 2 \times (n-1) + 2 \times (n). $$

Now, is there a rearrangement of $ \{ 1, 2, \ldots n-1, n \}$ that will allow us to achieve this maximum?

Comment: sorry if im being silly but where would i go from here

Comment: Where are you stuck? I've listed out a lot of steps, which do you not understand?

Comment: Im not sure how you got the second condition and im not sure how you can rearrange it to achieve the maximum length.

Comment: 1) $|a_i - a_{i+1} | = \pm (a_i - a_{i+1}$. So, if we consider the expansion, there will be $n-1$ +/- signs (first condition) and they must pair up (second condition). 2) (You have to check the middle, esp for small cases) Once we know that's the maximum, it's pretty easy to pair up to satisfy the second condition. Give it a try with $n=5$ (large enough to ignore small cases of $n=2, 3$).

Comment: what does check the middle mean? For 5 i understand the path is 3 1 5 2 4. Im just not sure about the proving parts

Comment: Because we have $2(n-1)$ terms and not $2n$ terms, so not all of the coefficients are 2.

Comment: So, for $n=5$, the maximum is achieved at: $ -2 \times 1  - 2 \times 2 + 1 \times 3 + 1 \times 4 + 2 \times 5$. (See where checking the middle is important?) How does this lead us to the sequence $3, 1, 5, 2, 4$? In fact, it also leads us to the sequence $4, 1, 5, 2, 3$ (because both sequences satisfy the condition 2).

Comment: thank you. That does make sense but how u write a rigorous proof out of all this.

Comment: What I have above is a rigorous approach, but you will need to internalize the ideas more. (The "checking the middle" part slightly obscures what is going on, especially if this is your first time dealing with absolute value inequalities this way)

Comment: im not exactly sure how you get the values in -2 x 1 -2 x 2... and im not sure how to internalize the idea more. The checking the middle still confused me and is there any way to show the rearrangement that will allow us to get the maximum